# Excel Formula for City

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any specific formula for Excel by which I can automatically get the last cell filled in with the city name only from the address?

For instance, I would like to pick up the city name from the address and have it placed in city column. Is there any such formula? Please refer to snapshot:

[image]

Address
Knoting Hill, Main road Manchester

City
manchester

Comment: what is the format of your address? is it comma separated? I cannot see your screenshot unfortunately due to our webfilter

Comment: Wales is a country....

Answer (score 0):

If all your city names only have one word in them, then do `Text to Columns` under the `Data` tab with the delimiter set as space. If the format is similar, then it should give you a Column populated only by City names.

You can play around with that tool, such as first doing text to columns delimited by a comma, to filter out the first bit of the address

Comment: Select your data, click text to columns, click next and on the next window select "Space" from the check box, then click next and finish, your address should now cover 4-5 columns with a single word in each

Comment: Thx got it. But How can i drag this for 5000 rows?

Comment: select the column with the address (you can do this by clicking the letter corresponding to where your address data is)